# PHP not finding array values labeled by strings

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

So I have a while loop that generates google maps markers:

```
<?php
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $lat2 = $row['usrhomelat'];
    $lon2 = $row['usrhomelng'];
    echo 'var icon = customIcons[ ' . $row['gender'] . '];';
    echo 'var miLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(' . $lat2 . ',' . $lon2 . ');';
    echo 'var marker = new google.maps.Marker({';
    echo 'position: miLatLng,';
    echo 'map: map,';
    echo 'icon: icon.icon';
    echo '});';
}
?>
```

and grabs the appropriate icon from this array:

```
var customIcons = {
            male: {
                icon: 'https://5d31037421'
            },
            female: {
                icon: 'https://5d310374214f1
            },
            0: {
                icon: 'https://5d310374214f
            },
            1: {
                icon: 'https://5d310374214f1d0670ef
            },
            2: {
                icon: 'https://5d310374214f1d0670e
            }

        };
```

I am wondering why when the associated array component is an integer, it works, but when it is a string, i.e. 'male' or 'female' I get and uncaught reference error: male is not defined.

I could temporarily switch those array values over to integers to solve the problem but will likely need them as strings later, so I am just solving this issue before there are too many to switch over.

Sincere thanks for any help-a

Answer (score 0):

You have to give in single or double quotes:

example:

```
'male', 'female' etc
```

Integer array index, either you may give with our with out quotes, but string index you must give inside the quotes.

so try:

```
var customIcons = {
            'male': {
                'icon': 'https://5d31037421'
            },
            'female': {
                'icon': 'https://5d310374214f1'
            },
            0: {
                'icon': 'https://5d310374214f'
            },
            1: {
                'icon': 'https://5d310374214f1d0670ef'
            },
            2: {
                'icon': 'https://5d310374214f1d0670e'
            }

        };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for responding. That didnt work, unfortunately.

Comment: I actually just got it, haha. SHould have tried this much earlier: echo 'var icon = customIcons[ "' . $row['type'] . '"];';  just needed an extra set of quotations.